# MySQL DB and two separate tables 1:M

Tags: mysql

I have two separate tables already created and filled with info. The first table has a unique field called hostname. Each host name may have more than one record in the second table. I already created them and the hostname is inserted in both tables. Now, how can I connect them?

I'm using MySQL workbench. I have to create foriegn key in table2, and this key should be the hostname. Now if I want to insert in table2 before inserting into table1. Is this possible? i.e, my program run in a way that it inserts the information of table2 before table1.  Is there any change in the insert statement? Do I have to specify anything about table1 when inserting in table2?

Comment: You have to refresh your knowlage about 1, 2 and 3 NF - this link may be useful for you http://databases.about.com/cs/specificproducts/g/1nf.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a foreign key, it *must* always reference a valid record or be NULL. If you need to insert into `table2` before `table1`, you must first insert the `table2` record with the foreign-key column NULL, then insert the `table1` record, and finally update the `table2` record with the reference to `table1`.

It's an odd analogy, but think of it like building a house. If you build it on-site before laying the foundation, you have a problem. But, you can build it somewhere, then build the foundation, then move the house onto it.

Now, on a side note, I do have to question why you are inserting `table2` before `table1`...

Comment: Ok. I've updated the program logic and I can insert records to In table1 first. The insert statement for table2, do I need to specify anything to relate this table to table1? I just want to ensure as this is what it seems to me from what I have read. I only need to specify the foreign key during table2 creation or update, but it has nothing to do with the insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

The FOREIGN KEY constraint is used to prevent exactly what your program does.

It will not allow you to create a detail record (your table2) having a hostname value that does not exist in the master hostname table (your table1).

Either you have to change how your app works or do not connect the two tables. In the later case you will have to maintain yourself the data integrity between them.

You will have to periodically test for new hostnames in the detail records and create them if they do not exist.

I suspect that you are having log records written all the time in the table, but you also need a hostname "master file" keeping info for every host.

If this is the case (or s similar one), just do not connect the tables and maintain the hostname master file manually (i.e. with some stored procedure that is scheduled to run and do the table1 maintenance).